# iOS UILocalNotification set to fire once every day, once every two days, and only on Sundays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to use a settings bundle to schedule a UILocalNotification. In settings, you can choose if you want the notifications to come daily (1/day), 1 every 2 days, only on Sundays or never.

Here is the code I used (this is all in AppDelegate.m):

```
    -(void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        NSString *testValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"multi_preference"];

        NSLog(@"%@", testValue);

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

        NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents* compoNents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today]; // Get necessary date components

        [compoNents month];[compoNents day];

        NSDictionary *dictToday= [self getDataFromdate : [compoNents day] month:[compoNents month]];


        if ([testValue isEqualToString:@"one"]){
            UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:20];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
            localNotification.alertBody = [dictToday objectForKey:@"saint_description"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

             }
        if (testValue==Nil){
            UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:20];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
            localNotification.alertBody = [dictToday objectForKey:@"saint_description"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

        }
        if ([testValue isEqualToString:@"two"]){

            UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:86401];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
            localNotification.alertBody = [dictToday objectForKey:@"saint_description"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

        }

        if ([testValue isEqualToString:@"three"]){
        NSDate *today2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        // Get the weekday component of the current date
        NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                                           fromDate:today2];

        /*
         Create a date components to represent the number of days to subtract from the current date.
         The weekday value for Sunday in the Gregorian calendar is 1, so subtract 1 from the number of days to subtract from the date in question.  (If today is Sunday, subtract 0 days.)
         */
        NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [componentsToSubtract setDay: 0 - ([weekdayComponents weekday] - 1)];

        NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract
                                                             toDate:today2 options:0];

        /*
         Optional step:
         beginningOfWeek now has the same hour, minute, and second as the original date (today).
         To normalize to midnight, extract the year, month, and day components and create a new date from those components.
         */
        NSDateComponents *components =
        [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                               NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: beginningOfWeek];
        beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];



            UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.fireDate = beginningOfWeek;
            localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
            localNotification.alertBody = [dictToday objectForKey:@"saint_description"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

        }
    }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)
                                                 name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (locationNotification) {
        // Set icon badge number to zero
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
return yes;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{




    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today's Saint"
                                                    message:notification.alertBody
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    if (notification.alertBody!=Nil)
    [alert show];


     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Is the code correct for launching the notifications as I've stated?
If not, what's the problem with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are scheduling notifications whenever the user changes preferences. However, you never *unschedule* previously scheduled notifications, which is why you are observing bursts of notifications at times that will correspond exactly to the times you repeatedly changed settings a day or two days ago.

The notifications you schedule are different objects than the set of notifications that you intend to modify. Unfortunately, `UILocalNotifications` have no identifier tokens.

However, you can unschedule all previous notifications whenever you receive a `defaultsChanged:` message with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` *before* you reschedule. This will solve your problem.

Also have a close look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257878/1916766) which suggests to cancel and reschedule notifications even upon launch to avoid bursts or duplicate notifications when a user re-installs your app.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using the cancelAllLocalNotifications method but I don't know why, I forgot to paste it here. The thing is, now they aren't launching when they should. For instance, if I use localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:20]; and localNotification.repeatInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit; it will launch the notifications daily, at the time 20 seconds from now?

Comment: Maybe you are using it in the wrong place? `cancelAllLocalNotifications` should be the first thing you do in the method you pasted.

Comment: I've updated the code. But the notifications just aren't launching when they should. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, no `cancelAllLocalNitifications` anywhere else other than the rescheduling method.

Answer (score 2):

I have two ideas,

First: what's the value of dictToday ?

```
NSDictionary *dictToday= [self getDataFromdate : [compoNents day] month:[compoNents month]];
[dictToday objectForKey:@"saint_description"]
```

If this value is nil, your notification will not pop.

Second: Check your time zone and the time zone returned from:

```
[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]
```

You could be on a +3 time zone and setting your localnotification to fire on a negative time zone and that is never going to happen.